# Spring Boot POST getting bad request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having 400 bad request error, it is only happening for the post request, I am using @PostMapping. When I send the JSON object using postman it does not work I get the 400 bad request error. Please help if somebody can.

Here is the Controller:

```
 package com.backend.ShoppingList.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.backend.ShoppingList.model.Store;
import com.backend.ShoppingList.service.StoreService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Control {

    @Autowired
    StoreService storeService;


    // create stores
    @PostMapping(path = "/createstore", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Store> create(@RequestBody Store newStore) throws Exception {
        Store store = storeService.saveStore(newStore);
        if (store == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(store, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the Postman request (the best would be to export the curl)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD7SW.png

Comment: please add `Store` class code to the question. A problem might hide there, for example if you use `int` or `Integer` field for `newStore` and trying to parse `50576739648` to it, which exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE - `2147483647`

Comment: @AndrewThomas may be right.

Comment: @AndrewThomas you are really great. That is exactly was what happening. How do I close this case?

Comment: @ErnestoOrozco you can edit your post by adding `Store` class code and console log on the thrown exception, and I'll be able to post full answer

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is your path:

you use : https://[domain]/createstore

but your path is : https://[domain]//createstore

Either remove the annotation @RequestMapping("/") or remove the path attribute in the @PostMapping annotation, it depends on other implementation.

Comment: I suppose with wrong path matching he would get 404 NOT FOUND or something else but definitely not 400 BAD REQUEST